# Entity framework groupby and then count individual columns

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

I have an entity framework query to join applications with ethnicity table and group by ethnicity (Id and options) and then get the total count for each ethnicity and then get the individual counts based on status {open, Closed, Draft.. etc) with Iqueryable as I will need to use pagination for this query to get first 'x' or go to page 'y' so I cannot do toList and then get the values.

The current EF query is very slow and it's taking more time.

Can anyone help me to achieve the same result in a better way if possible?

```
 var query = from app in Context.Application
                    join eth in Context.Ethnicities on app.EthnicityId equals eth.EthnicityId
                    group app by new
                    {
                        eth.EthnicityId,
                        eth.EthnicityOptions
                    }
                    into ethAgg
                    select new EthnicityView
                    {
                        Id = ethAgg.Key.EthnicityId,
                        Ethnicity = ethAgg.Key.EthnicityOptions,
                        Total = ethAgg.Count(),
                        Closed = ethAgg.Count(p => p.Closed),
                        Draft = ethAgg.Count(p => p.Draft ),
                        Inprogress = ethAgg.Count(p => p.Inprogress ),
                        Waiting = ethAgg.Count(p => p.Waiting),
                        Open = ethAgg.Count(p => p.Open )
                    };
```

Generated Sql

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Project7].[EthnicityID] AS [EthnicityID], 
[Project7].[C2] AS [C1], 
[Project7].[C1] AS [C2], 
[Project7].[C3] AS [C3], 
[Project7].[C4] AS [C4], 
[Project7].[C5] AS [C5], 
[Project7].[C6] AS [C6], 
[Project7].[C7] AS [C7]
FROM ( SELECT 
    [Project6].[C1] AS [C1], 
    [Project6].[EthnicityID] AS [EthnicityID], 
    [Project6].[EthnicityOptions] AS [C2], 
    [Project6].[C2] AS [C3], 
    [Project6].[C3] AS [C4], 
    [Project6].[C4] AS [C5], 
    [Project6].[C5] AS [C6], 
    [Project6].[C6] AS [C7]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [Project5].[C1] AS [C1], 
        [Project5].[EthnicityID] AS [EthnicityID], 
        [Project5].[EthnicityOptions] AS [EthnicityOptions], 
        [Project5].[C2] AS [C2], 
        [Project5].[C3] AS [C3], 
        [Project5].[C4] AS [C4], 
        [Project5].[C5] AS [C5], 
        (SELECT 
            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
            FROM   [dbo].[Application] AS [Extent16]
            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ethnicity] AS [Extent18] ON [Extent16].[EthnicityID] = [Extent18].[EthnicityID]
            WHERE ([Extent16].[Closed] = 1)
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [Project4].[C1] AS [C1], 
            [Project4].[EthnicityID] AS [EthnicityID], 
            [Project4].[EthnicityOptions] AS [EthnicityOptions], 
            [Project4].[C2] AS [C2], 
            [Project4].[C3] AS [C3], 
            [Project4].[C4] AS [C4], 
            (SELECT 
                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                FROM   [dbo].[Application] AS [Extent13]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ethnicity] AS [Extent15] ON [Extent13].[EthnicityID] = [Extent15].[EthnicityID]
                WHERE ([Extent13].[Closed] = 1)
            FROM ( SELECT 
                [Project3].[C1] AS [C1], 
                [Project3].[EthnicityID] AS [EthnicityID], 
                [Project3].[EthnicityOptions] AS [EthnicityOptions], 
                [Project3].[C2] AS [C2], 
                [Project3].[C3] AS [C3], 
                (SELECT 
                    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                    FROM   [dbo].[Application] AS [Extent10]
                    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ethnicity] AS [Extent12] ON [Extent10].[EthnicityID] = [Extent12].[EthnicityID]
                    WHERE ([Extent10].[Draft] = 1)
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
                    [Project2].[EthnicityID] AS [EthnicityID], 
                    [Project2].[EthnicityOptions] AS [EthnicityOptions], 
                    [Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
                    (SELECT 
                        COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                        FROM   [dbo].[Application] AS [Extent7]
                        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ethnicity] AS [Extent9] ON [Extent7].[EthnicityID] = [Extent9].[EthnicityID]
                        WHERE ([Extent7].[Inprogress] = 1)
                    FROM ( SELECT 
                        [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
                        [Project1].[EthnicityID] AS [EthnicityID], 
                        [Project1].[EthnicityOptions] AS [EthnicityOptions], 
                        (SELECT 
                            COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                            FROM   [dbo].[Application] AS [Extent4]
                            INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ethnicity] AS [Extent6] ON [Extent4].[EthnicityID] = [Extent6].[EthnicityID]
                            WHERE ([Extent4].[Waiting] = 1)
                        FROM ( SELECT 
                            [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
                            [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [EthnicityID], 
                            [GroupBy1].[K2] AS [EthnicityOptions]
                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                [Extent3].[EthnicityID] AS [K1], 
                                [Extent3].[EthnicityOptions] AS [K2], 
                                COUNT(1) AS [A1]
                                FROM   [dbo].[Application] AS [Extent1]
                                INNER JOIN [dbo].[Ethnicity] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent1].[EthnicityID] = [Extent3].[EthnicityID]
                                GROUP BY [Extent3].[EthnicityID], [Extent3].[EthnicityOptions]
                            )  AS [GroupBy1]
                        )  AS [Project1]
                    )  AS [Project2]
                )  AS [Project3]
            )  AS [Project4]
        )  AS [Project5]
    )  AS [Project6]
)  AS [Project7]
ORDER BY [Project7].[EthnicityID] ASC
```

Comment: did you try moving this code to Stored Procedure and calling SP from EF. i think that helps you in-terms of performance!

Comment: Idea: Create a view with all the aggregated and grouped data in the DB. Map this view to an appropriate model via EF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is no way we could achieve this from entity framework. 
I tried moving this query to a stored procedure and split the individual counts and invoke that stored proc from entity framework.